# Cache api (json) request to avoid repeating the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faraday

So I created this request which gives me a response as json.

```
require 'dotenv/load'
require 'faraday'

class OverviewController < ApplicationController

  def api_key
    ENV["API_KEY"]
  end

  def url
    "https://example.com"+api_key
  end

  def index
    conn = Faraday.new(url, request: {open_timeout: 1, timeout: 1}) do |c|
      c.response :json, :content_type => /\bjson$/
      c.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
    end

  response = conn.get url
  @hash = response.body['data']

  end
end
```

Response:

```
{
    "type": "products",
    "version": "x.x.x",
    "data": {
        "Product 1": {
            "title": "xxx",
            "attributes": {
                "x"=1
            },
            "id": 22,
            "name": "Product 1"
        },
        "Product 2": {
            "title": "xXx",
            "attributes": {
                "x"=2
            },
            "id": 25,
            "name": "Product 2"
        },
...
```

This works great so far. But since the data in this json changes really rarely and there is a policy to not request the api as much I would like to cache my result.

I tried different solutions with "faraday-http-cache" but I can't get it to work. But I like to not use another lib.

I read the "rails - Guides - caching" segment and I think I need **low level caching** `Rails.cache.fetch`

I would be really glad if someone could help me :-)

EDIT(after Panic's comment):
I tried this, but I need some more help

```
require 'dotenv/load'
require 'faraday'

class StatsClient

  def api_key
    ENV["API_KEY"]
  end

  def url
    "https://example.com"+api_key
  end

  def index
    conn = Faraday.new(url, request: {open_timeout: 1, timeout: 1}) do |c|
      c.response :json, :content_type => /\bjson$/
      c.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
    end

  response = conn.get url
  @hash = response.body['data']

  end
end

class OverviewController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @hash = Rails.cache.fetch('something', expires_in: 15.minutes) do
      StatsClient.products
    end
  end
end
```

Like this? What has to go actually as **`'something'`**. Also I get the error that "StatsClient.products is not recognised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code from your controller into a separate class (or module) `StatsClient`. Then in your controller:

```
def index
  @hash = Rails.cache.fetch('something', expires_in: 15.minutes) do
    StatsClient.products
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution but I cannot get it to work. I edited my question.

Comment: @mrdmr In your code you need to replace `def index` with `def products`, `StatsClient.products` with `StatsClient.new.products`, and `@hash = response.body['data']` with `response.body['data']`